# JSP session.getAttribute exception error

Tags: java, jsp, session

So I'm trying to make a shopping cart using sessions.
If I add an item for the first time it'll succeed but if I add another one It'll return as exception error.
(I already declare session.setAttribute("i","0") when you login as a member)

Here's the doAddCart.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" language="java" import="java.sql.*" errorPage="" %>
<%
    String id = request.getParameter("id");
    String qty = request.getParameter("qty");
    String temp = (String)session.getAttribute("i");
    int temp2 = Integer.parseInt(temp)+1;
    session.setAttribute("i",temp2);
    temp = Integer.toString(temp2);
    session.setAttribute(temp,id);
    session.setAttribute("q"+temp,qty);
    response.sendRedirect("../product.jsp");
%>
```

here's the error I get

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /Controller/doAddCart.jsp at line 5

2: <% 
3:  String id = request.getParameter("id"); 
4:  String qty = request.getParameter("qty"); 
5:  String temp = (String)session.getAttribute("i"); 
6:  int temp2 = Integer.parseInt(temp)+1; 
7:  session.setAttribute("i",temp2); 
8:  temp = Integer.toString(temp2);


Stacktrace:     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)  org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722) root cause

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String  org.apache.jsp.Controller.doAddCart_jsp._jspService(doAddCart_jsp.java:68)  org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)  javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722) note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.29 logs.
```

does anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line assumes session["i"] is a string:

```
String temp = (String)session.getAttribute("i");
```

This line sets session["i"] to an Integer:

```
session.setAttribute("i",temp2);
```

Remove line 7 and add this at the bottom instead, that will keep the attribute as a String:

```
session.setAttribute("i",temp);
```

Comment: But it won't perform the increment.

Answer (score 1):

Try this line

```
session.setAttribute("i", String.valueOf(temp2));
```